# keras model reaches almost 100% validation accuracy but prediction always returns 1

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

I am new to tensorflow and am trying to build a model to classify two classes of images.

Validation accuracy reaches 98% after 12 epochs (which seems abnormally high). When predicting, it always outputs: [[1.]] regardless of the inputted image

Loading data:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
import pickle

dataDir = "C:/optimised_dataset"

categories = ["demented", "healthy"]

IMG_WIDTH = 44
IMG_HEIGHT = 52
lim = 0

training_data = []

def create_training_data():
    for category in categories:
        path = os.path.join(dataDir, category)  # path to demented or healthy dir
        class_num = categories.index(category)
        lim = 0
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
            if lim < 3000:
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
                    training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
                    lim+=1
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            else:
                break

create_training_data()

random.shuffle(training_data)

X = []
Y = []

for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 1)
Y = np.array(Y)

pickle_out = open("X.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

pickle_out = open("Y.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(Y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
import pickle
import numpy as np

X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
Y = pickle.load(open("Y.pickle", "rb"))

X = np.array(X)
X = X/255.0
Y = np.array(Y)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs=18, validation_split=0.1)

model.save('DD1.model')
```

prediction:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

categories = ["demented", "healthy"]


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_WIDTH = 44
    IMG_HEIGHT = 52
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_array = img_array / 255.0
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, 1)


model = tf.keras.models.load_model("DD1.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('D:/test.png')])

print(prediction)
```

when I delete `img_array = img_array / 255.0` it outputs a seemingly random decimal between 0 and 1.

Comment: check if your data is highly imbalanced.

Comment: hmm.. I replaced the data with another dataset and that worked. But I don't understand why my original data yield a 98% validation accuracy

Answer (score 0):

As I already suggested, the reason for such cases is class imbalance in most cases.

Let's say, you have two classes, class A with 96 samples, and class B with 4 samples in the training set. In such extreme cases, if we start with a model which always predicts class A, it will achieve 96% accuracy.

To solve this issue, you can try -

1. assigning class weights.

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                                 np.unique(y_train),
                                                 y_train)


model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight=class_weights)
```

2. try data augmentation to increase number of samples in the minority class.
3. instead of accuracy, use f1 score to evaluate your model.